# Requiring sprockets and rack

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rack, sprockets

I am writing a web application that loads starts Websocket right after the initial page load. It uses the gems `sprockets`, `rack`, `thin` and `em-websocket`. When I require the files in this order:

```
require "sprockets"
require "rack"
require "thin"
require "em-websocket"
```

the application runs and the Websocket communication succeeds, but when I bring `sprockets` after `rack`:

```
require "rack"
require "sprockets"
require "thin"
require "em-websocket"
```

Websocket does not start. At the moment, my code does not use anything from `sprockets`. It is just loaded, but not used yet. Why is this not running?

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What happens exactly?

Comment: It looks like the initial page rendering succeeds, but the Websocket communication that is supposed to begin right after it does not.